# How can I add a space between name and surname in a R markdown (Twenty seconds format)?

Tags: spacing, cv, rmarkdown

I have made a CV using a R markdown template called Twenty Seconds Format from the Vitae package. However I cannot add a space between name and surname so they run together. I am a real beginner and this is my first time using r markdown. Does anyone know how to add a space? Or failing that how to edit the positioning of the surname to move it slightly to the right? Thanks!

```
name: Marie
surname: Curie
```

I have also tried this which also didn't work:

```
name: "Marie "
surname: "Curie"
```

[image: Output PDF]

Answer (score 1):

I went trough the code of R markdown template you mentioned, there is a bug in it.

```
% Path to file on GitHub: https://github.com/mitchelloharawild/vitae/blob/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/twentyseconds/resources/twentysecondstemplate.tex

% Incorrect code (line number 72):
\cvname{$name$$if(surname)$$surname$$endif$} % Your name

% Corrected version with an extra space:
\cvname{$name$$if(surname)$ $surname$$endif$} % Your name
```

Search for file `twentysecondstemplate.tex` in your computer, and change that line, then recompiling should solve the problem.

Note: The same file also has this piece of code in the footer of the resume, there the author has the needed space.

If that works for you, file a bug report on the author of that template/package.

Lastly, a similar implementation of Twenty Seconds Resume is available on overleaf, and is a latex-only implementation! In case you are unable to (for some reason) find and fix the R markdown template then that is another option:

```
% Path to overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/twenty-seconds-curriculum-vitae/kfgsngtymkfj
```